# Spring/tomcat Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.driver

Tags: spring, spring-boot, annotations, inversion-of-control, autowired

Lately I have been trying to learn spring boot.  I have the following relevant files:

- an @Configuration class: I use this to generate the entitymanagerfactory
- an @Entity class: I use this to map to a mysql table instance
- an @Repository crudrepository interface: this is built in to spring
- an @Controller class: this is used to test auto-wiring (when I can inject, I will move this to the service layer)
- an @SpringBootApplication class: this runs my application
- an application.properties file
- a pom.xml: this is used for maven and includes mysql jar

an entity class mapped to a mysql table and a UserRepository class(annotated with @Repository).  I am trying to inject the crudrepository class via @Autowire annotation, but spring is having difficulty creating the datasource for it because it cannot find the mysql driver.  What confuses me is that I have the mysql dependency in maven and I am deploying this on a glassfish 4 server, but Spring is trying to use apache tomcat to connect to the database.  Below is my stack trace, code snippets, and mysql-connector:

**Relevant Stack Trace (inner exception)**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.driver
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
... 62 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.driver
```

*notice how this is trying to use org.apache.tomcat to create datasource, even though I am using a glassfish server.  Does this matter?*

**Source Code: the first relevant exception occurs when spring tries to inject the datasource bean that is a parameter to this method and can't create it**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class AppConfigUtil {

@Autowired
@Bean 
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) { 
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean bean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean(); 
    bean.setPackagesToScan("com.connor"); 
    bean.setDataSource(dataSource); 
    return bean.getObject(); 
}
```

**Maven (pom.xml) for mysql jar:**

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

**application.properties: this is the entirety of my application.properties file spring uses to generate datasource**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/craigslist
spring.datasource.username=dbadmin
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.driver
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=true
```

**Here is picture of my maven dependencies: the mysql jar is present:**
[downloaded maven dependencies: including mysql jar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKjfs.jpg)

**Any ideas on how to fix this?**

Comment: You don't need the `AppConfigUtil` Spring Boot configures all that for you. You don't need the `spring.datasource.driver-class-name` Spring (and hibernate) will automatically know the driver to load. Also the driver should be `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` and not `com.mysql.jdbc.driver`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Spring boot.
Here are some things you can do to make it work (You might have done some of these, I added anything I can think of just to make sure):

- Remove your AppConfigUtil class because Spring boot will "magically" find the datasource for you if your application.properties is configured right.
- Add `@SpringBootApplication` to your `ConnerApplication.java` class
- Add `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency in your pom

Some side notes:
`@Autowire` is not intended to be marked with `@Bean` annotation. @Autowire CAN be used to autowire bean which is annotated with `@Bean`.

**EDIT :**
I realized that OP wants to deploy it on Glassfish. In that case, you will need to tweak Spring to produce a deployable war file and configure your application container (glassfish) to include a jdbc driver. All of it is doable but requires a lot of efforts.
I suggested that you go with embedded tomcat approach if you use Spring-boot for new project. It is basically battle-ready. You can hardly go wrong with this.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Minjun.  I have taken your advice and "removed" (commented out the whole) appconfig file.  I then checked, and the class that runs the program is annotated with the following annotations: @SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.connor"})
@EntityScan(basePackages={"com.connor.model"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={"com.connor.dao"}) 
@EnableAutoConfiguration().  My pom.xml also contains the specified dependency.  I clean/install my project again, and still no luck.  Is there anything else I should look at?

Comment: If your SpringbootApplication class is at the root package which is `com.conner` (looks like it is from your picture), then only @SpringBootApplication is sufficient. This might not directly solve the problem though. Is there any new error message?

Comment: I followed your suggestion and commented out all the annotations but the @SpringBootApplication one on my driver class.  However, I am still getting the same error.  Should I look at somehow including the mysql jar in the tomcat directory itself?

Comment: I re-read your question and realized you want to deploy the spring application on Glassfish. That means you will tweak Spring to produce a war file instead of "embedded-tomcat-jar" file. You also need to configure glassfish to include a jdbc driver so that when war file is deployed, it will find the jdbc-driver at runtime. All of this requires a lot of efforts, mind let me know why you want to use glassfish for spring while spring already provide a "standard-production-ready-embedded-tomcat" solution?

Comment: Hi Minjun, I was unaware that spring tries to package my application for deployment on a tomcat server (I had assumed that I could choose whatever server I liked to deploy it, as I have done with regular jee apps in the past).  How should I configure my tomcat installation so that it has a mysql jdbc jar; should this be done in maven or via dropping the jar file in the tomcat installation directory?

Comment: The answer for this does not fit in this thread. You can google "spring boot how to deploy war without embedded tomcat", you will get plenty of help. Trust me, you will most likely go back to embedded tomcat eventually.

Comment: Thanks minjun.  I am going to try and stay with the embedded tomcat rather than use another server.  Now I just have to figure out why it is configured wrong.  I will google/look into this on my own.  Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need declare in `pom.xml`

`spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.driver`

You can read my configuration in a simple app using Spring Boot [here](https://github.com/yuen26/spring-mycontact/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.properties)

Beside, if you're using Spring Boot you don't need use codes "Source Code: the first relevant exception occurs when spring tries to inject the datasource bean that is a parameter to this method and can't create it..."